# ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'amazon.aws.ec2_instance'

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create an EC2 instance using Ansible, and I created a role for this EC2.

```
- name: launching AWS instance using Ansible
  amazon.aws.ec2_instance:
    key_name: xxxxx
    instance_type: xxxxx
    image: "{{ ami_id }}"
    region: ap-southeast-2
    wait: yes
    group: Ansible
    count: 1
    vpc_subnet_id: vpc-xxxxxxx
  register: ec2
```

I get the below error when I execute.

ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'amazon.aws.ec2_instance'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

Ec2 instance to be created.

Comment: This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. Take a look at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

The error says the problem is either:

- misspelling, missing collection
- or incorrect module path

The name of the collection is correct. Test it

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t module -l | grep amazon.aws.ec2_instance
amazon.aws.ec2_instance ...
```

This means Ansible can't find the module. See [COLLECTIONS_PATHS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#collections-paths) and take a look at your configuration. For example, if you install Ansible by *pip* locally for the user *admin*

```bash
shell> ansible-config dump | grep COLLECTIONS_PATHS
COLLECTIONS_PATHS(/export/test/ansible.cfg) = ['/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

Make sure the module is on the path. For example,

```bash
shell> ls -1 /home/admin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_instance.py 
/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ansible_collections/amazon/aws/plugins/modules/ec2_instance.py
```

Fit the [configuration](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_configuration.html#configuring-ansible) to your needs.